# Java Applet is not working in IE8

Tags: java, internet-explorer-8, applet

Java Applet is not working in Internet explorer 8. It just shown blank screen.
Maybe because of security restriction in IE8.

Is there any fix to this problem?

Comment: Please include how you are attempting to load the Java applet (i.e. the HTML code).

Comment: Does any applet work in IE8?  Does the applet work in any browser besides IE8? Where can we visit the broken applet? What is the output in the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml)? ..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try reinstalling Java? After reinstalling Java if Internet Explorer asks if you want to enable the Java addon, be sure to click the Enable button.

If you go to Internet Explorer->Tools->Options->Programs->Manage Addons (then Select in the combobox Show All Addons) is the "Java Plug-In SSV Helper" and "Java Plug-In 2 SSV Helper" set to "Enabled"?

Is the site hosting the applet an Internet site or an Intranet site?  Check the IE security options for Internet/Intranet Tools->Security->(Internet/Intranet)->Custom Level-> check to make sure "ActiveX Controls and Plugins" is set to "enabled".

Please post the HTML code (tags) that defines the applet.

Answer (score 0):

We are using 1.6_33 with Kronos and we have a pc now and then that gets a blank page after logging in.  We installed 7_25 and run the app until we get the prompt it is requesting to use the older version, 6_33. Click on run and after the app worked we uninstalled 7_25 and we were able to open the app with 6_33.  We also believe it is a security setting but not sure if it is java related or something to do with IE8 or a combination of both.