# Java Applet doesn't work in IE 8

Tags: java, internet-explorer-8, applet

I have an applet which is working in the Firefox but it doesn't in Internet Explorer 8. "Scripting of Java applets" in Tools | Internet Options is enabled. "Java Content in the browser" is enabled in the Control Panel and the Security Level is set to the lowest possible (Medium). "Java Plug-in SSV Helper" and "Java Plug-in 2 SSV Helper" are enabled as well. What else can I do?

This is how I embed the applet:

```
<applet code="attribute.class" codebase="/applet/" archive="/applet/attribute.jar, /applet/jna-4.0.0.jar" width="1" height="1">
  <param name="url" value="<?php echo $url ?>" />
</applet>
```

Comment: Could you provide an example link?

Comment: For example this: http://www.w3.org/2000/07/8378/object/java/clock doesn't work in IE8 but in Firefox. Is the Internet Explorer 8 too old?

Comment: There is lots of important information missing in your post: 1. What OS are you using (WinXP 32 or 64?) 2. Which Java version are you using e.g. 1.X.0_XX and in 32/64Bit? 3. The html code how you embed the applet is missing... For instance in Firefox I get 8 clocks - 4 embedded with the applet tag and 4 with the object tag. In the IE11 I only see the 4 clocks with the applet tag and the others are missing. So how did you embed your applet? Maybe you can update your post with that code.

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right. I am using WinXP 32 bit (in a VM) and Java SE 7 Update 2 (1.7.0_25). In Firefox 23.0.1 (on this VM) I get also 8 clocks. On IE8 I don't get any clocks.

Comment: Did you try to use DeployJava.js? Have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html
And Java SE 7 Update 2 (7u2)= 1.7.0_02 and Java SE 7 Update 25 (7u25)= 1.7.0_25.

Comment: @user2720736 In the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059465/java-applet-is-not-working-in-ie8?rq=1 t has been mentioned that you need two plugins to show java applets. Are these installed on your computer?